Python/kivy: rotating animation is not working
Problem is that
Animation of kivy is not working perfectly.rotate_value_angle is not getting change.
if not replaced:
            if self.ids.battelground.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                self.adjust_positions(card)
                val = random.randint(0,360)
                self.change_to_moncard(card)
                print(str(val))
                anim = Animation(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}, size=(90, 100),rotate_value_angle = val,duration=0.5)
                anim.start(card)
                

I was expecting that it will also change its angle. But it is just changing its pos_hint and size and also not giving any type of error.
DraggableCard
class DraggableCard(DragBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self, initial_pos_hint, w=100, h=150, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (w, h)  # Unique identifier for the card
        self.initial_pos_hint = initial_pos_hint
        
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.drag_touch = touch
            if self.parent:
                self.parent.bring_to_front(self)
                self.card_x_positions = sorted(widget.initial_pos_hint['center_x'] for widget in self.parent.children if isinstance(widget, DraggableCard))
            return True
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if hasattr(self, 'drag_touch') and touch is self.drag_touch:
            parent_width = self.parent.width
            parent_height = self.parent.height

            new_center_x = self.center_x + touch.dx
            new_center_y = self.center_y + touch.dy

            self.pos_hint = {
                'center_x': new_center_x / parent_width,
                'center_y': new_center_y / parent_height
            }

            return True
        return super().on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if hasattr(self, 'drag_touch') and touch is self.drag_touch:
            del self.drag_touch
            if self.parent:
                
                self.parent.handle_card_drop(self, self.card_x_positions, touch)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)


MonCard class
class MonCard(ButtonBehavior, RotateBehavior, Image):
    pass

Function by which I changed to MonCard
 def change_to_moncard(self, card):
        card.__class__ = MonCard
       
           

And you can see result
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Pydroid3/Monster Card Mania/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-08-04_19.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.4 (main, Sep 30 2023, 10:54:38) [GCC 11.4.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.2.0, git-Unknown, 2024-07-31 (installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[WARNING] [KivyMD      ] Version 1.2.0 is deprecated and is no longer supported. Use KivyMD version 2.0.0 from the master branch (pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r19p0-01rel0.###other-sha0123456789ABCDEF0###'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G71'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: android
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
198
241
114
359
324
51
254
133
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...


Thanks for you answer

As far as I understand, you drag and drop an image and expect it to rotate, try doing the following.
First of all, Since the image is a widget, you can transform the matrix
with self.canvas.before:
   PushMatrix() 
   self.rotate=Rotate(angle=0,axis=(0,0,1),origin=self.origin)
with self.canvas.after:
   PopMatrix() 

We've set Rotate value to it, now we can access it.
And PushMatrix and PopMatrix need to import from kivy.graphics
anim=Animation(angle=val, duration=0.5)
anim.start(self.rotate) 

Please note, this is a separate animation, also I hope that it will work, if anything writes to me, and I hope the translator translated everything correctly :)

It is showing error that [self.origin] is not defined within MonCard

Try then to specify the center of your widget
